# search with specific date sql

Tags: sql, database, date

I want to data for a specific date in SQL.

This is the structure  of my db:

- Column 'date'  date format '2011-02-07 09:42:56'

I want to get all rows from column 'user' from month '02' as well as day '07'

Comment: For what database?  Date handling can be very different between them.

Comment: Does this query need to care about the year too? or just all rows that occured on 'Feb 7' regardless of the year?

Comment: You need to specify the datatypes of the column, not the "structure" As you have phrased it, we cannot be sure as to whether you are  talking about a column that actually contains character data, (formatted as you have specified) or a true datetime value which is only being formatted for display purposes. This distinction is critical and determines how easy the solkution will be.

Comment: "from month '02' as well as day '07'" - In any year or just 2011? Also I see you have edited this question and completely ignored all requests for info about the column datatype and RDBMS you are using (-1)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from datesTable 
where ((DATEPART(mm, date) = 2) and (DATEPART(dd, date) = 7))
```

Comment: DATEPART is TSQL/SQL Server, when DATE in SQL Server doesn't include time -- why would you provide this answer, and why did someone feel it deserved an upvote?!

Comment: Works on my SQL Server 2005... it may be that using "date" as the column name... is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,clmDate) AS n_Year,
DATEPART(mm,clmDate) AS n_Month, 
DATEPART(dd,clmDate) AS n_Day     
FROM tblName
WHERE ' write condition'
```

get Only Month , date and year Details